# Reflecting Light From Glossy Material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, glass, reflection

I am trying to emulate the dichroic glass effect with the cycles. I can create the light passing through effect using the "is Shadow Ray," but I can't get the reflection without getting it diffused.

[image: This is the node setup]

[Shadow coloring tutorial is here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EN_xB9Fkw9M)

[image: this is the outcome]

Rather than diffused blue reflection lights, I want this perfect(!) reflection:

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this effect?